# why E dominates v?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, kruskals-algorithm

I analyzed the running time for Kruskal algorithm and I come up with O(ElogE+Elogv+v)

I asked my prof and he said that if the graph is very sparse with many isolated vertices V dominates E which makes sense if not then E dominates V and I can not understand why? 
I can give an example where graph is not sparse but still V is greater than E

Can anyone help me to clear this confusion?

Comment: How do you define sparse? My guess is your prof's definition of sparse is that V dominates E.

Comment: Actually he believes if I dont make-set for isolated vertices in kruskal alg then E dominates V

Comment: The number of edges can be anywhere from 0 to `V choose 2 = (V(V-1))/2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) in a undirectional graph has `|V|-1` edges.

Since a tree is the connected component with least edges as possible - it basically means that for each connected undirectional graph, |E| is in `Omega(|V|)`, so |V| is dominated by |E|.

This basically means that if `|E| < |V|-1` - the graph is not connected.

Now, since Kruskal algorithm is designed to find a spanning tree, you can abort the algorithm once you have found `|E| < |V|-1` - there is no spanning tree at all, no point to look for one.

From this **we conclude** that when `|E| < |V|-1`, there is no point in discussing complexity of Kruskal Algorithm, and we can safely assume that `|E| >= |V| -1` , so `|V|` is dominated by `|E|`.

Answer (score 0):

Density = number of edges / number of possible edges = E / (V(V-1))/2

Let the graph be a tree E = V - 1

So V = (E + 1)

And Kruskal's complexity is

O(E log E + E log V + V) = O(E log E + E log (E + 1) + (E + 1)) = O( E log E )

So E dominates. E will dominate as long as E = O(V).

Comment: `V dominates iff E = O(1).` **No.** what if for example `E=O(logV)`? V still dominates E, so the claim is obviously wrong.

Comment: @amit Oops! Thanks for catching that!